# Best way to Check remote database after fix time interval

Tags: android

I want to develop this simple instant messenger application. Now i can send text to database. Now i want to show a notification to the user if he receives a new message.For that i think i want to check the remote database after fix time i.e every 20 sec. What is the best way of doing that??

I know my question could end up being lame and this might not be the best technique to show user notification of new message but for now i just know that so i am implementing it . .

Suggestions are always welcome . .

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer in a service, so it can occur even if the app is not in the foreground.  As an aside, I wouldn't do it every 20s-  far too often, if you got a significant user base it would cost you a lot of bandwidth.  Back it off to less frequent-  every 60 seconds is probably sufficient.

Comment: So is there an alternate solution as it is costly. i tried using sockets on php and connect it from android sockets but i am using free webhosting and individual child process is not allowed there :-( how can i implement a chat application then ?

Comment: Use a web service, so it all comes across as HTTP requests.  As an aside-  20s is reasonable for a chat program, where you expect people to be actively looking at the screen.  Or perhaps a changing time based on whether you're the foreground activity or not.

Comment: Actually i am pretty new to android development. and i am not getting what you saying. can you  please be more specific  ???

Comment: What I'm saying has nothing to do with Android.  Its basic network programming.  I suggest you look up web services in google and read some tutorials.  Its probably been the most common way of communicating between servers and apps for most of a decade.